# Как выбрать записи за определенный месяц в Битрикс?

Tags: php, битрикс

Нужно получить список подразделений за определенный месяц.

```
$arFilter = array(
        "IBLOCK_ID" => 5,
        "ACTIVE_DATE" => "Y",
        "ACTIVE" => "Y",
        '>=UF_DEP_BIRTHDAY' => "01.04.2018",
        '<=UF_DEP_BIRTHDAY' => "01.05.2018"
    );
```

Вот примерно так.

Год не должен учитываться.

Comment: Ну и в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Формат даты смени, на

```
$start = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( "01.04.2018" ));
$end = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( "01.05.2018" ));

$arFilter = array(
        "IBLOCK_ID" => 5,
        "ACTIVE_DATE" => "Y",
        "ACTIVE" => "Y",
        '>=UF_DEP_BIRTHDAY' => $start,
        '<=UF_DEP_BIRTHDAY' => $end
    );
```

фильтр по такому формату что ты написал не будет работать.